# ORA-00904: invalid identifier. "TT"."H_NO": invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm inexperienced at Oracle, I don't understand where I'm doing wrong.My query is running MSSSQL smoothly but I get an error in oracle.

```
ERROR ( AND MTH.M_NO =TT.H_NO) MALIYET)
ORA-00904: "TT"."H_NO": invalid identifier.
```

```sql
select TT.H_NO, 
       TV.H_TARIH,
       TV.H_BITTAR,

       ( SELECT SUM(
                  ( M_SYTOPLAM
                  + M_COCUK
                  + M_YAKACAK
                  + M_MTOPLAM
                  + M_FMTOPLAM
                  + ( ( M_SSKI + M_EK2 + M_EK1)
                    + M_TISVEREN
                    + M_HOLKES
                    + M_HOLKES1
                    )
                  - M_BRUTKES
                  + M_ESIPRIM
                  + M_ESARTIS
                  + M_XEK9
                )
                - ( CASE
                    WHEN CHARINDEX('05510',NVL(MTK.M_CHR1,MTH.M_EKKOD2)) > 0
                    AND  MTH.M_XSGRT=1
                    THEN ROUND((MTH.M_SSKM + MTH.M_EK3) * 0.05,2)
                    ELSE 0.00
                    END
                  + ( CASE
                      WHEN MTH.M_XSGRT = 1
                      AND  RTRIM(NVL(M_EKKOD2,' '))='05746'
                      AND  MTH.M_SSKI>0
                      AND  MTH.M_XEK4 =0
                      THEN ROUND((MTH.M_SSKM - ROUND(((((MTH.M_TARTIS*2))/(MTH.M_SSKI))*MTH.M_SSKM),2))*.05,2)
                      ELSE 0
                      END
                    )
                  )
                )
         FROM   H_MATRAH MTH
                INNER JOIN H_MATEK MTK
                ON MTH.M_NO=MTK.M_NO      
                   AND MTH.M_YIL=MTK.M_YIL
                   AND MTH.M_AY=MTK.M_AY
                   AND MTH.M_SKOD=MTK.M_SKOD
                   AND MTH.M_YIL = 2020
                   AND MTH.M_AY = 3
                   AND MTH.M_NO =TT.H_NO
       ) MALIYET
from   TERFNAKL TT
       INNER JOIN TERFNAKLV TV
       ON TT.H_NO=TV.H_NO
```

Comment: Post the schema for `TERFNAKL`.

Comment: It seems your version of oracle is causing you the problem. Here is the fiddle `https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=aca5b86ba7105f48cf19e74d4fb20504`. If you switch to 18c, it has no problem while 11g R2 shows the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Use like the below in your version of Oracle

REPLACE

```
   AND MTH.M_NO =TT.H_NO
```

WITH

```
   WHERE MTH.M_NO =TT.H_NO
```

I have run few test for identifying the issue

The below doesn't work

```
select (select tt.today  from dummy1  tb 
INNER JOIN dummy1 tc on  
tb.branch_code=tc.branch_code 
and tb.eof=tc.eof 
and  tb.branch_code=tt.branch_code )
from dummy2 tt
```

The below works

```
select (select tt.today  from dummy1  tb 
INNER JOIN dummy1 tc on  
tb.branch_code=tc.branch_code 
and tb.eof=tc.eof 
where  tb.branch_code=tt.branch_code )
from dummy2 tt
```

Comment: thank you for your help @psaraj.I applied your suggestion.I'm getting a different error. ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
Process ID: 1648
Session ID: 198 Serial number: 39564

Comment: wc @OnurÖnder refer this link for troubleshooting http://www.dba-oracle.com/m_ora_03113_end_of_file_on_communications_channel.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you have the tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tt ( h_no ) AS
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE mth ( m_no ) AS
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE mtk ( m_no ) AS
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Then the query:

```sql
select h_no, 
       ( select mth.m_no
         from   mth
                inner join mtk 
                on  (   MTH.M_NO=MTK.M_NO 
                    AND MTH.M_NO = tt.H_NO )
       ) maliyet
from   tt;
```

Gives the exception:

> ```
> ORA-00904: "TT"."H_NO": invalid identifier
> ```

But if you move the filter condition you are using for correlation out of the `JOIN` condition and into a `WHERE` clause (in the outer level of the correlated sub-query):

```sql
select h_no, 
       ( select mth.m_no
         from   mth
                inner join mtk 
                on ( MTH.M_NO=MTK.M_NO )
         WHERE  MTH.M_NO = tt.H_NO
       ) maliyet
from   tt;
```

Then the query outputs:

> ```
> H_NO | MALIYET
> ---: | ------:
>    1 |       1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=39a82021a3e3d318c4d3e5854f5bdd51)*

If you upgrade to a more modern version of Oracle [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=39a82021a3e3d318c4d3e5854f5bdd51) then your correlated query works.

Also, `CHARINDEX` is not an Oracle function. Instead, you need to use `INSTR`.